# Enforce getter setter access at the interface level

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I want to enforce access on getter or setter for a property at the interface level so that the same be followed in the class that implements it. I want to do something like below:

```
public interface IExample
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
}

public class Example : IExample
{
    private string _name = String.Empty;
    string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        internal set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately from what I know this is not allowed in C#. I think that is because interface are meant to only expose what that is with a public access(I haven't the slightest idea!).

What I need here is a way to implement this using any other coding pattern (preferably using interface) which will help me to enforce specific access on getter or setter of a property in all of its implemented classes.

I googled this and tried to go through MSDN docs for this but had no luck!

Comment: you cannot enforce that via interface

Comment: This is not how interfaces work. They are meant to define public access. Use an abstract class for your problem.

Comment: No. As far as my search through google and docs goes, interfaces are not meant for it is what conveyed!

Comment: @Mafii That would result in data hiding, which I don't think is the intention here.

Comment: @Mafii: That is what I thought earlier but then I don't have anything concrete here to put in an abstract class except for this enforcement of access on the getter/setter. And yes as Drew mentioned, that would result in data hiding. What I want is that anyone who's implementing the interface should not be allowed to give access to getter/setter of a implemented property (I mean through a class or interface) more than what that is allowed as part of the design.

Comment: @BenisonSam sadly this is not part of the C# language. Interesting approach tho.

Answer (score 1):

Using `internal` on a setter is somewhat nasty anyway but if you really want to do it you could define a second interface that is itself internal AND make `Example` `internal` to your assembly.

```
public interface IExample
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
}

internal interface IExampleInternal
{
    string Name
    {
        set; get;
    }
}

internal class Example : IExample, IExampleInternal
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Now anything in the same assembly can take an `IExampleInternal` and outside only ever gets to see `IExample`. You do however have to list both interfaces on every class you create.

Comment: That's a really cool solution you gave there but unfortunately it'll only work from inside the assembly. My motive here is to expose the Example class publicly and at the same time expose the IExample interface publicly by keeping the setter of the Name property internal (which again the language doesn't support). I know its a bit too much but that's the requirement. Is there any other construct or design pattern which can help me to achieve that?

Comment: Not really, the setter can't be `public` (needed for an interface) and `internal` at the same time. Maybe reconsider why you want to expose Example publicly: in a modern IOC-based application we typically expose an interface and keep the concrete implementation hidden in our assembly. That way, as a consumer of this assembly it's easy to mock and test without having to test BOTH assemblies at the same time. If you want to expose it so people can `new` it, consider adding a factory to make `IExample` objects.

Comment: I think Factory pattern is something with which I can try to resolve this problem. I  was trying to understand how factory pattern works. But then if  I allow the consumer of my assembly to use the interface IExample outside the assembly to implement and create his own class, the only way make sure that he goes with an internal setter for the property Name is by giving proper documentation as on why that is required as there seems no way enforcing it on the consumer of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? This can be a workaround:

```
// Assembly: A
public interface IExample
{
    string Name { get; }
}

// Assembly: B
using A;

public abstract class Example : IExample
{
    public string Name { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class SpecificExample : Example
{
    public void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        // Can be set because it has protected accessor
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IExample e = new SpecificExample()
        {
            // Can be set because it has internal accessor
            Name = "OutsideAssemblyA"
        };
    }
}

// Assembly: C
using A;

public abstract class Example : IExample
{
    public string Name { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class AnotherSpecificExample : Example
{
    public void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        // Can be set because it has protected accessor
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IExample e = new AnotherSpecificExample()
        {
            // Can be set because it has internal accessor
            Name = "OutsideAssemblyA"
        };
    }
}
```

This works but you have to create (or copy-paste) the `abstract class Example` in every assembly in which you would like to create a specific implementation of it, e.g. `SpecificExample` or `AnotherSpecificExample`.

Comment: This will work @Gabor but not really a work around for me as in my scenario the abstract class part is something which will have to be written by the implementer of the interface. Because here I am providing both the interface as well as the implemented class as two separate and independent usable units as a part of my assembly package wherein the interface would facilitate the consumer of the package to develop a class that would be similar in pattern with the Example class by implementing the IExample interface.

Comment: If this is the scenario you can only put XML comments on the interface where you describe that an abstract class must be created that implements this interface the way that the setter is protected internal. Of course it will not enforce nothing but if the developer who will implement this interface will see this note. :)

Comment: Yes. That's a good suggestion Gabor. Though technically through the code I am not enforcing anything, but I can give definitely give the guidelines through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible. As everybody told you, interfaces are meant to define public access. How about the following code ?

```
public interface IExample
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code leaves it up to the implementer of the interface what the access should be for the setter of the Name property which is not the intention here. I want the setter access to be internal or protected.